# Spring Cron Expression - Not Running on Schedule

Tags: spring, cron, spring-scheduled

> 0 * 9-18 * * MON-FRI

I have this cron expression, I want to run @Scheduled every minute from 9am to 6pm during weekdays (monday to friday). For some reason its not running.

I tried to debug by doing

> 0 * * * * MON-FRI

But this one is running the task.

What am I missing? Requirements are

- Run every Minute
- Run from 9am to 6pm
- Run on weekdays Monday to Friday

Answer (score 0):

Your Cron Expression `0 * 9-18 * * MON-FRI` seems incorrect. Please Use The following in order to achieve your desire results

```
0 0 9-18 ? * MON-FRI *
```

It will run  `At second :00, at minute :00, every hour between 09am and 18pm, every day between Monday and Friday, every month`

Please visit following [cronGenerator](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) website in order to generate your expression and check your expressions are right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, it should be.

> 0 * 9-18 ? * MON-FRI *

[image]